# Retrieving Profile Picture from Firebase issue - Swift

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, uiimageview, firebase-storage

I am getting a weird issue where I am unable to retrieve the profile picture from the firebase database. I am not getting any errors, & The ImageView for the picture appears, however there is no image within it. Where am I going wrong?

Here is my code in my ViewWillAppear:

```
/** Profile Picture **/
        profilePicture.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width / 2.975, y: self.view.frame.height / 3.925, width: self.view.frame.width / 3 , height: self.view.frame.height / 5)
        profilePicture.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        profilePicture.layer.borderWidth = 3
       // profilePicture.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicture.layer.frame.width/2




   let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)

    ref.child("pictureforprofile").observe(.value, with: {(snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in


        let imageUrl = snap.value as! String
        print(imageUrl)


        self.profilePicture.sd_setImage(with: URL(fileURLWithPath: imageUrl))

        self.view.addSubview(self.profilePicture)
        self.reloadInputViews()




    })
```

When I print out the imageUrl, it comes out as:

```
 https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wavelength-official.appspot.com/o/profilePicture%2F4348A9F6-A49B-4FF4-BC14-83081684E8FA.jpg?alt=media&token=a842bda6-59b0-42dc-bf24-8dbb839e7231
```

This is what my database looks like on Firebase
[image]

--- So I have resolved this issue thanks to answer below! Here is the code below, incase anyone has this issue in the future!

```
/** Profile Picture **/
    profilePicture.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width / 2.975, y: self.view.frame.height / 3.925, width: self.view.frame.width / 3 , height: self.view.frame.height / 5)
    profilePicture.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    profilePicture.layer.borderWidth = 3
    // profilePicture.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicture.layer.frame.width/2

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)

    ref.child("pictureforprofile").observe(.value, with: {(snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        let imageUrl = snap.value

        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        _ = storage.reference()
        let ref = storage.reference(forURL: imageUrl as! String)
        ref.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if error != nil {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            } else {

                self.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.view.addSubview(self.profilePicture)
                self.reloadInputViews()
            }
        }


       // self.profilePicture.sd_setImage(with: URL(fileURLWithPath: imageUrl as! String))


    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firebase you can't use the URL for your firebase storage. If you decided to store your image on to IMGUR or an FTP server the solution you came up with would work fine. However you must use the url you retrieved from firebase and download it with their Storage API

```
// Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
let storage = Storage.storage()
let storageRef = storage.reference()
let ref = storage.reference(forURL: imageURL)
ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
   if let error = error {
     // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {

     self.profilePicture = UIImage(data: data!)
    self.view.addSubview(self.profilePicture)
    self.reloadInputViews()
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way that I could potentially provide a default image for it? or would I just load an image into the view until the the download is complete?

Comment: No problem! To provide a default image drag and drop an image to your .xcassets. Before you download try 'self.picture=someImage' and add it to your view.